# Find $\cos\theta$ where $‖\mathbf{a}‖=6, ‖\mathbf{b}‖=8, ‖\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}‖=11$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

This is a question from AOPS that I don't really understand. I would love it if someone can show me how to do this question from the very beginning.

> Given vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ such that $\|\mathbf{a}\| = 6,$ $\|\mathbf{b}\| = 8,$ and $\|\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}\| = 11.$ Find $\cos \theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}.$

I don't know (not I don't understand but I don't know) how to find $\mathbf{a}$ or $\mathbf{b}$ since it's not a number but a vector.
This is supposed to be a lesson next year and I'm trying to preview but I really don't understand this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128126/discussion-on-question-by-celine-find-cos-theta-where--mathbfa6--math).

Answer (score 2):

hi~ I just reread your comments and realized u aren't trying to say i'm posting competition questions and we solved that out
sorry for my tone

1. $\|a\|= 6$
2. $\|b\|= 8$
3. $\|a+b\|^2= (a+b)\cdot(a+b)$

(rainbow method) $\to$

4. $(a+b)\cdot(a+b) = \|a\|^2+2(a\cdot b)+\|b\|^2$
5. $11^2=121$
6. $121=\|a\|^2+2(a\cdot b) + \|b\|^2=100+2(a\cdot b)$
7. $2(a \cdot b)=21$
8. $a \cdot b=21/2=10.5$
9. $\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta=10.5$
10. $6 \times 8 \cos \theta=10.5$
11. $48 \cos \theta=10.5$
12. $\cos \theta= 10.5/48$
13. $\cos \theta=21/96=7/32$